# Converting controls from MM to Inches in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a lot of controls in my XAML in the form of
TextBlock: TextBox.

So for example:

XSize(mm):25.4

YSize(mm):50.8
etc

Now when the user clicks on an option to use imperial units I want to change all textBlocks + textBoxes to something like

XSize(in):1

YSize(in):2

etc

What is the best way to go about this ?

Comment: Without code, it is usually hard to guess what the exact problem is, and guessing for answers is usually the only thing anybody can do. If you provide a piece of code of your previous attempts, it will be a lot easier to understand what the exact problem you're having is. That piece of code can even be code that doesn't work at all, because it would still give a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Converters`. Create a `MM` to `Inch` converter and use that converter to change the values when the user inputs a value on the certain value.

Sample usage of a converter. **You have to define a static resource under the resources of your view for the controls you want to use the converter with**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <spikes:Convertaaa x:Key="Convertaaa" />
</Window.Resources>
<ComboBox x:Name="OptionsToChoose"/>
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Convertaaa}">
            <Binding ElementName="OptionsToChoose" Path="SelectedValue"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Text"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**Converter.cs**

```
public class Convertaaa : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Implement conversion here. values[0] will give you the selected option values[1] will give you the value to convert, then do a return
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This assumes that you do know `MVVM` pattern in WPF and `Bindings`. If you are doing behind the code, then you probably want to hook up to the `TextChanged` of your `TextBox` and instantiate a new `Converter` Class and call the `Convert` method and set the `Text` property of the `Textbox`.

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer.  Wouldn't you at least need a MultiBinding, since the value depends on two inputs (the length number, and units)?

Comment: Then you want to do MultiBinding and set the MultiBinding Converter to the MM and inch. The Convert method now will accept object[] values.

Comment: You need multibinding to determine whether you convert from mm to inches or from mm to mm (i.e. do nothing)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use a style on the Textbox instead of duplicating all the code ?. For the MultiBinding, I use two properties in my ViewModel to bind to, one is a bool IsMetric and the other is a unique object for each textbox. Is it possible to do a style for that ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible as long as you make sure that the `DataContext` of each `TextBox` is not the same.